# Can't use "get" expression inside "interpolate"

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to move a text field using the `text-translate` and `interpolate` features.

But if I use the `get` expression inside `interpolate` to gather a property from the source, it stops working.

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Sample:

```dart
'text-translate': [
  'interpolate',
  ['exponential', 2],
  ['zoom'],
  0,
  [
    'literal',
    [0, 0]
  ],
  20,
  [
    'literal',
    [
      0,
      ['get', NAME_OF_PROPERTY],
    ],
  ]
],
```

If I don't use `get` there, it works perfectly fine, so there might be something wrong with that expression.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting your `get` inside a `literal` expression, so it's being treated as a literal.

I'm not certain, but perhaps the second part of your expression should be:

```
20,
[0, ['get', NAME_OF_PROPERTY]]
```

or perhaps:

```
20,
[['to-number', 0], ['get', NAME_OF_PROPERTY]]
```